# Regexp pattern - SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag b

Tags: javascript, regex

I created this pattern in java, and now I'm trying to use it in javascript. Why am I getting this error?

```
var pattern = /b(?=[A-Z\d]{9,10}\b)(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*/b;
```

`SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to use "word boundaries"?  That would be `\b` (notice the direction of the slash).

```
var pattern = /\b(?=[A-Z\d]{9,10}\b)(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\b/;
```

You also need `//` as delimiters.

Comment: Yes, word boundaries is what Im trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such flag as "b" in javascript regexes.

Here's [the list of available flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).